# Using multiprocessing to assign values to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a code similar to this:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

a = np.zeros((4, 4))  # 4x4 array containing zeros

def f(x, y):
    # uses scipy functions
    # takes long to compute
    #result = <someValue after calculation>
    global a
    a[x][y] = x+y  # simple example function

# since f takes long to compute, I want to run it in parallel
jobs = []
for x in range(4):
    for y in range(4):
        p = mp.Process(target=f, args=(x, y))
        p.start()
        jobs.append(p)

# wait for a to be filled for the next step
for j in jobs:
    j.join()

print a  # prints an array of zeros!
```

Why are the values not assigned to a and how can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: This is off-topic because it is a basic low-level programming question which is not specific to computational science, and should probably be asked (and has likely already been answered) on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiprocessing creates separate Python processes (i.e. UNIX or Windows process) for each `mp.Process` that you asked it for. These *do not* share memory. If you want them to operate on the same data, you must use one of the managed data types in the `mp.Manager` class to explicitly communicate between separate tasks.

FWIW, this is pretty slow since whatever object you put into the `mp.Manager` containers is pickled before it's communicated.